# What's JSTL? What are JSP Tag Libraries? What are the differences?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

I have read a lot about this! But I can't make a clear idea! JSTL is used to avoid Java code in JSP files. I see many variant! `<jsp:useBean>` or `<c:out>`...
And sometimes, people refer to them as Tag Libs.

I think that I miss something here! Help please. What's JSTL? What are Tag Libraries? Are there any differences?
In some situations, you need a c.tld file, but I never heard about a jsp.tld file. Why is that?

Comment: Breathe deeply and put your mouse above the `[jstl]` tag which you have put below the question yourself, wait until a black box shows and then click therein the *info* link. This kind of information is by the way also covered in the Java EE tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Tag libraries are pieces of Java code that can be used within a JSP, but which conform to a certain API and which look like HTML tags in the JSP.
- A tag library description file (TLD) describes the names of these tags, what attributes they can have and what Java classes implement them
- The Java Standard Template Library (JSTL) is a specific standardized tag library
- `<jsp:useBean>` is *not* a tag library tag (despite looking like one). It's an action defined in the JSP standard. Yes, this is questionable design.